# How to declare a 2D array within a class in C++?

Tags: java, c++, multidimensional-array

I want to declare a 2D array within a class. The size of the array will be initialized in the Constructor. In Java, I can perform this operation as

```
public class A {
  public int[][] indices;

  A(int a,int b){
     indices = new int[a][b];
  }
}
```

How can I perform the same operation in C++?

Comment: Use a 2D vector or custom matrix.

Comment: Do you require `indices` to consist of contiguous memory like a 2D array would be, or do you just want to be able to index them as if it were a 2D array?

Comment: I don't need contiguous memory.

Answer (score 3):

Use a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<squares>> squares;
```

And initialize in constructor:

```
squares.resize(xPos);
for (int i = 0; i < xPos; i++) {
    squares[i].resize(yPos);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In c++ a more popular way for a 2D array would be to use a 2D vector. This would have many advantages.

1. You could also access on elements via `[][]`.
2. The size is dynamically allcoated - so you could always increase the size by a `myVector.push_back(vec)` or `myVector[i].push_back(x)`.

To shortly describe it, it is something like an `ArrayList` in `Java`.

So maybe use a

```
#include <vector>
public class A {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> indices;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As there are already solutions to your answer, i would suggest something different.
Dealing with 2D or multi-D arrays. I think pointers are much faster than vectors. You can always argue that we should make the best use of technology. But then i would suggest you to use a library called `uBLAS` which makes processing of arrays easy.
The docs can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) and use it like:

```
int main () {
    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
    matrix<double> m (3, 3);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m.size1 (); ++ i)
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < m.size2 (); ++ j)
            m (i, j) = 3 * i + j;
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a raw array like so in C++ class

```
class C {
    int** someArray;
    public: 
        C() {
            someArray = new int*[ SIZE_GOES_HERE ];
            for( unsigned int j = 0; j < SIZE_GOES_HERE; ++j )
                someArray[ j ] = new int[ SECOND_SIZE ];
        }
};
```

Just remebr to mange the memry later
 What this does is declare a double pointer which will poin at an array of pointers which will point at arrays creating a 2d array.